# PyOWM Daily Weather Icon

Tags: python-3.x, openweathermap

I've studied the PyOWM and OWM API guides and some code recipes and have things working fine in a larger bit of code but I just can't work out how to get get the current weather icon for todays forecast? Here's a code snippet that works apart from the icon:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
import requests, json

def checkInternetRequests(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=3):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError as ex:
        print(ex)
        return False

def get_weather():
  if checkInternetRequests() == True:
    # 52.5766° N, 1.5438° W
    print ("Internet Up")
    CITY = "Atherstone, GB"
    LON = 1.54
    LAT = 52.576 
    API_KEY = "myapikey"
    ICON_URL_1 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"
    ICON_URL_2 = "@2x.png"
    owm = OWM(API_KEY)
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    one_call = mgr.one_call(lat=LAT, lon=LON)

    print (one_call.forecast_hourly[3]) #works - 3hrs from now
    print ("===========================")
    print (one_call.forecast_daily[0]) # works - Today
    print ("===========================")
    print (one_call.forecast_daily[0].weather.icon)

  else:
    print ("Internet Down")
    time.sleep(10)

get_weather()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather1.py", line 37, in <module>
    get_weather()
  File "weather1.py", line 31, in get_weather
    print (one_call.forecast_daily[0].weather.icon)
AttributeError: 'Weather' object has no attribute 'weather'
```

Where am I going wrong ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK - After a few beers and some food plus 4hrs of messing with the code I have this working !

```
one_call.forecast_daily[0].weather_icon_url()
```

gives me a url I can use to display the forecast icon in my code for today.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.utils import timestamps, formatting
from pyowm.owm import OWM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

observation = mgr.weather_at_place('London')
w = observation.weather
icon = w.weather_icon_url(size='2x')

img = mpimg.imread(icon)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)